# Break CSS into rules

Tags: javascript, css

I have the content of a CSS file as a string I got with an AJAX request.

I need to break it into rules that I can feed into `styleSheet.insertRule`

What is the best way to achieve this correctly and efficiently ? I do not want to include/write a full CSS parser just for that if possible ...

I considered simply splitting on '}' but this will not work if there are @media clauses which created nested curly brackets, and I am not sure it is correct otherwise ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a new `<style>` element using the stylesheet text you have and insert it into the `<head>` element.

```js
var style = `
div {
  color: blue;
}`;

setTimeout(function() {
  var elem = document.createElement("style");
  elem.innerHTML = style;
  document.head.appendChild(elem);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: that will not work for me, I need to insert the rules into a particular stylesheet at a particular place - basically I'm replacing an @import statement with those rules

Comment: You should be able to append the css to an existing stylesheet declaration. You will just need to find that particular `<style>` element, and append new CSS as HTML to it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Nisarg Shah probably does the job, but here's an alternative. It uses the [`css.js`](https://github.com/jotform/css.js) library to parse the CSS string into a JS array, which can then be inserted using `stylesheet.insertRule()`.

The two advantages this method has:

1. It breaks the CSS into rules as stated in the question
2. It would allow styles to be filtered or altered before insertion

Also, this is a simplified solution that ***will not*** work with more complicated CSS containing media queries or similar rules. For a more robust solution, the function would need to handle those types of style rules, and more info on how to do that can be found in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

Here's the approach:

1. Get the CSS from your API
2. Parse the CSS into a JS array of objects
3. Loop through the CSS rules and create the CSS style string
4. Add the style string to the stylesheet with `insertRule()`

```js
var cssString = `
div {
  color: green;
  font-size: 24px;
}`;

setTimeout(function() {
  var parsedStyles = addStylesAndReturnParsedStyles(cssString);
  console.log(parsedStyles)
}, 1000);

var addStylesAndReturnParsedStyles = function(cssString) {
  var parser = new cssjs();
  var parsed = parser.parseCSS(cssString);
  var styleEl = document.createElement('style'),
      styleSheet;

  // Append style element to head
  document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

  // Grab style sheet
  styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;

  parsed.forEach(style => {
    var selector = style.selector;
    var rules = style.rules;
    var propStr = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
      var prop = rules[i];
      propStr += prop.directive + ':' + prop.value + ';\n';
    }

    // Insert CSS Rules
    styleSheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + propStr + '}', styleSheet.cssRules.length); 
  });
  
  return parsed;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jotform/css.js/master/css.min.js"></script>
<div>Here's some content</div>
```

Comment: thx but seems like an overkill, I don't need a complete parse, just separating the rules